Execution order of useEffect hook in React
I'm trying to learn React hook but I'm not able to understand why the useEffect hook's callback is run after the re-render. It just unnecessarily causes one extra render. If React lets useEffect execute first, then all the data can get ready before the render, and hence, the number of renders decreases.
I'm new to React, so forgive me if this is a trivial question.
I've tried exploring many existing answers on stackoverflow and saw several youtube videos but all they are telling is when is useEffect called.

Why do you need to know that, is it just for the sake of curiosity or do you have any specific case that is giving you trouble because of this? At first thought, there are some things that are initialized before the first render, i.e. [val, setVal] = React.useState("val") <- react state is initialized before executing first render.

It just unnecessarily causes one extra render. What are you doing in the effect that causes a render? If you're doing something asynchronous (eg, fetching data), then you would always need two renders, even if useEffect ran before render. And synchronously setting state in a useEffect is rare, so if you tell us what you're doing, maybe we can point you towards a better way to do it

@NicholasTower I was doing a synchronous task—a simple app to calculate sum of 1 to n.  I have an input box which onChange change the state which causes the App to re-render. And to calculate the new result useEffect also runs which then set the result which causes another render. If useEffect was called earlier before rendering then there would be one less render.

Based on the description i don't think that should be done in a useEffect. I would guess that the calculation should be done either in the onChange function or during rendering. If you provide your code, i can give a more definitive recommendation. Also, this page in react's documentation may be useful: https://react.dev/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect
